# MATLAB Getting a floating point out of a DAT files with mixed strings, integers and spacing

Tags: matlab, fopen, scanf

I am working with an external software within MATLAB. This software gives me an output .dat file in which I want to extract a piece of information.

The .dat file contains the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
 Vortex Lattice Output -- Total Forces

 Configuration: Fokker F27 FRIENDSHIP                                       
     # Surfaces =   2
     # Strips   =  40
     # Vortices = 320

  Sref =  35.000       Cref =  2.4325       Bref =  14.500    
  Xref =  18.531       Yref =  0.0000       Zref =-0.70925    

 Standard axis orientation,  X fwd, Z down         

 Run case:  -unnamed-                              

  Alpha =   3.93282     pb/2V =  -0.00000     p'b/2V =  -0.00000
  Beta  =   0.00000     qc/2V =   0.00000
  Mach  =     0.274     rb/2V =  -0.00000     r'b/2V =  -0.00000

  CXtot =   0.06409     Cltot =  -0.00000     Cl'tot =   0.00000
  CYtot =  -0.00000     Cmtot =   8.27673
  CZtot =  -1.19843     Cntot =   0.00000     Cn'tot =   0.00000

  CLtot =   1.20000
  CDtot =   0.01826
  CDvis =   0.00000     CDind =   0.01826
  CLff  =   1.20138     CDff  =   0.01945    | Trefftz
  CYff  =  -0.00000         e =    3.9315    | Plane  


 ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to extract the numeric value next to the Alpha string, which is 3.93 in this case. The output file always has the same layout and thus the Alpha string is always in the same location, its value only changes.

I've tried using `fopen` with `textscan` and `fscanf` but I fail to obtain the data from the file.

Is there a way to do this automatically in MATLAB?

Comment: Try to look for that string, and get the next 8 chars. HINT: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html?refresh=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution for those who don't have the luxury of tables as these were introduced in MATLAB R2013b.

I manually parsed the file line by line and found the line that contained the `Alpha` string.  Once I found it, I removed all spaces for this line, then I use a regular expression to look for the following pattern:

```
[a-zA-Z]+=-*[0-9]*\.*[0-9]*
```

This pattern searches for:

1. `Alpha`
2. ... followed by an equals sign
3. ... followed by a possible dash for negative values
4. ... followed by a possible sequence of numbers
5. ... followed by a possible period
6. ... followed by another possible sequence of numbers

If you strip out all of the spaces, you will only get one match which is the output you desire:

```
Alpha=3.93282
```

Simply extract out the first token, then find the `Alpha=` string and strip that out.  Finally, convert the desired number from string to numeric.

---

Here's the code:

```
%// Open up the file
f = fopen('test.dat');

%// Go through the file...
while true
    %// Get a line
    line = fgetl(f);

    %// Have we reached the end of the file? Get out then
    if line == -1
        break
    end

    %// If we find a line with the Alpha string in it...
    if ~isempty(strfind(line, 'Alpha'))

        %// Strip out all spaces
        line = strrep(line, ' ', '');

        %// Find the pattern discussed above
        cel = regexp(line, 'Alpha+=-*[0-9]*\.*[0-9]*', 'match');

        %// Remove the Alpha= string
        cel = strrep(cel, 'Alpha=', '');

        %// Convert the string value into a numeric value and store 
        %// this in a variable called value
        value = str2double(cel);

        %// Get out of the loop
        break;
    end
end

%// Close the file
fclose(f);
```

Comment: You are right, the MATLAB R2013b is a luxury. Hence, Ill go with your approach since it probably work on somewhat older MATLAB versions.